# How to get value depending on list selection in spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet strictly for listing called "List":

[image]

I have another where I enter data called "Data":

[image]

I was able to figure out how to reference a list from another sheet doing a google search. On the "Data" sheet I can choose a dealer on the A2 drop down menu. When I choose a dealer I want it to automatically populate the value to "Amount" from "Dealer's Amount" corresponding to the dealer from the "List" sheet. The "Dealer's Amount" in the "Data" sheet should just be read-only. I don't have Microsoft Excel, so I'm doing this from Google sheets.

How do I go about finding  solution? I'm not sure how to phrase it in search engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `VLOOKUP`

---

On sheets `Data` cell `B2` you will enter the formula: `=VLOOKUP(A2, List!$A$2:$B$4, 2, 0)`